# How to get string fields from sphinx RT index

Tags: sphinx

Can't get the title field from the below table,

RT Structure have the below fields,

```
id, gid, title
```

But when run below query can't get the title field,

```
SELECT * FROM rt WHERE MATCH('test');
+------+--------+------+
| id | weight | gid |
+------+--------+------+
| 1 | 1643 | 123 |
| 2 | 1643 | 234 |
+------+--------+------+
```

How to get the title field from rt index ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get `field`s out. Fields are indexed, but they are NOT stored.

You only get `attribute`s. Can make `title` BOTH a `field` and an `attribute`.

```
rt_field = title
rt_attr_string = title
```

then can insert into it...

```
INSERT INTO rt ( id, title ) VALUES ( 3, 'third row' ), ( 4, 'fourth entry' );
```

Which will use it for both.